# Request email from OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I am trying to integrate oauth authentication from an MVC 4 project to Microsoft (Live service). The followings lines in AuthConfig.cs have been uncommented:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
            clientId: "XXX",
            clientSecret: "XXX");
```

And, the app has been set up at https://manage.dev.live.com

Later, when OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication is called, I get back the success status, but the email field is not in the returned data.

How can I request an email to be returned from VerifyAuthentication call issued again Microsoft account?

Thanks.

Comment: Look here http://mvcdiary.com/2013/03/01/how-oauthsecurity-to-obtain-emails-for-different-oauth-clients-but-microsoft-client-doesnt-return-email-it-didnt-include-scope-wl-emails/

Answer (score 0):

First, you should implement a 'MicrosoftScopedClient' class which implements 'IAuthenticationClient ' interface, and that should implement two methods of interface which is;

public class MicrosoftScopedClient : IAuthenticationClient
{ 
    //Define following three keys in Web.Config file and use it in code, it will maintain code consistency.
    private string clientId;
    private string clientSecret;
    private string scope;

```
private const string baseUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf";
private const string tokenUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf";

public void RequestAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
{
    //Getting values of clientId, clientSecret and scope from Web.Config file

    clientId=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientId"].ToString();
    clientSecret=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientSecret"].ToString();
    scope=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msScope"].ToString();

    string url = baseUrl + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) + "&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(scope) + "&response_type=code";

    //this will authenticate the user and register(only if user visited first time).
    context.Response.Redirect(url);     
}


public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context)
{
    string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

    string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.ToString();

    //removing code portion
    rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");

    IDictionary<string, string> userData = GetUserData(code, rawUrl);

    if (userData == null)
        return new AuthenticationResult(false, ProviderName, null, null, null);

    string id = userData["id"];
    string username = userData["email"];    // here you'll get email id of user
    userData.Remove("id");
    userData.Remove("email");

    AuthenticationResult result = new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, id, username, userData);
    return result;
}
```

}

////// Finally you need to register all stuffs in AuthConfig.cs and interact with Microsoft through our application.
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new MicrosoftScopedClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientId"].ToString(),
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["msClientSecret"].ToString(),
    "wl.basic wl.emails"
    )
    , "Microsoft", null);